# The operator $x(t)\mapsto x(t^2)$ in $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

I'm trying to prove that the operator $T:\mathcal{C}([0,1])\rightarrow\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ defined as $[T(x)](t)=x(t^2)$ is a bounded (or equivalently continuous) operator in the $(\mathcal{C}([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ Banach space.

As a first step I was trying to see if for all $x\in\mathcal{C}([0,1])$, exists some $M>0$ such that $|x(t^2)|<M|x(t)|$ for some $t\in[0,1]$ (considering Weirstraß Theorem the maximum would be reached in the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ for some $t$).
Any hint to formalize this approach?

Comment: You don't want $|x(t^2)|<M|x(t)|$ with $t$ on both sides.  Instead, you want $|x(t^2)| < M\|x\|_\infty$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bounded linear transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123070/bounded-linear-transformation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t_0\in[0,1]$ be such that$$|x(t_0)|=\max_{t\in[0,1]}|x(t)|=\|x\|_\infty.$$Then, since $t\mapsto t^2$ is a bijection from $[0,1]$ into itself,\begin{align}\bigl\|T(x)\bigr\|_\infty&=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\bigl|T(x)(t)\bigr|\\&=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\left|x\left(t^2\right)\right|\\&=\left|x\left(t_0\right)\right|\\&=\|x\|_\infty.\end{align}So, $T$ is an isometry. In particular, it is bounded.